# Add tag automatically when composing a note via C-c C-z (org-add-note)

Tags: org-mode

I want to give headings to which I add a note (via `C-c C-z` / `org-add-note`) a tag "note".

Similar to the ATTACH tag, I would like to use the following function to toggle the tag "on":

```
(org-toggle-tag "note" 'on)
```

How do I run the function with the / a appropriate "post-command-hook"?

I also log DONE, RESCHEDULE and REDEADLINE. I wouldn't mind if such entries do also end up with a `:note:` tag.